# regarding tab bar controller

Tags: iphone

I want to show more tahn four tab bar item on tab bar controller by scrolling tab bar . is it possible in iphone if it is.. please give the exact solution.??

Hoping your positive response

Comment: You need to at least _try_ to make the question title vaguely descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SDK creates a kind of "favourites" option automatically, so the user can drop their favourite icon to the tabbar..

Maybe you can extend the UITabbar and implement a "scrolling/swiping" mechanism, but I suggest you not to do that. This because swiping on a menu (tabbar) can be really annoying for the end user and they probably drag their "most-use" icons to the tabbar so don't worry about that. My advise: Save your time, and put it into more interesting features for your app instead of spending hours figuring out how to make a scrolling tabbar...

You can also make your own UIView and "duplicate" the tabbar, so it looks like a tabbar but it actually isn't, but again that's a complete different approach...

Comment: I don't think apple would approve it anyway. They want their UI Elements to be used as provided, I don't think they would be very happy with a tabbar that looks like their own but features a totally different behavior...

Comment: Oh yes they approve it, it's just a feature for your app and the only difference with the original is that it has scrolling... Ofcource like I said, use the original tabbar and spend your time doing more "useful" things ;-)

Comment: I would add that it's usually better to stick to the default behavior. Your user won't be lost. Or, if you want to have a scrolling tabbar that does not behave like the default one, then make it look different from the default one so that the user does not expect it to behave like the default one.